# RStudio not opening: error while loading shared libraries libicuuc.so.57

Tags: r, shared-libraries, rstudio, icu

I asked for the IT guy to install Magick++ onto my Debian 10 system and it must have updated some libraries and now RStudio is not working. He undid the installation and it did not help and reinstalling RStudio also did not help. I do not know best practise to install old libraries after a newer one is available, but is that the only way I can get RStudio running again?

Both R and RStudio seem to run from the terminal but use a different profile (I noticed that some of the packages that I use on my project are not listed as installed packages when I open R or Rstudio in the terminal). I searched for the v57 which is not there  but different version (eg 60-something are). Is there a way to tell RStudio to use those? Or anyone have any other ideas?

This is what happens when I try to open R Studio using my r project file:

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 1.4.1717, "Juliet Rose" (df86b69e, 2021-05-24) for Debian 9

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 127.

Error output:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*/home/ali/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-ali.log*

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11  Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
13 Feb 2024 16:42:17 [rsession-ali] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::executeSafely(rstudio_boost::function<void()>) src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:239; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::{anonymous}::processEvents() src/cpp/session/SessionHttpMethods.cpp:99
13 Feb 2024 16:42:17 [rsession-ali] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(rstudio_boost::shared_ptr<rstudio::session::HttpConnection>, rstudio_boost::function<void()>) src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:150
```